# How to write a function that searches a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a script that searches a fixed column with a list of words stored (assume its the range A:A) and I'd like to check if a particular string (the input to the function) is a substring of any of the words in that fixed list. If it is I want to replace it with the word in the list, if its not I don't want to do anything i.e. keep the original word.

Comment: Show us what you're trying.

Comment: function Search(ByVal s AS String) if InStr(s,A:A) >0 then ... end function

Comment: Edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: @Bond's suggestion is a good one. You need to show us what you've tried and how it's going wrong to help us help you. StackOverflow has some great guides on how to best show your kaputt code. Here's an excellent [general guide to asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and here's a [guide to creating a minimal but complete example of your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try editing your question to show us what you've done and where it's gone wrong, and the SO community will be crawling over each other to help you.

Comment: if I knew how to do it I wouldnt be asking ....I just posted all ive done

Comment: Functions cannot change any value on a worksheet other than the cell that they are in. Use a `Sub` procedure instead.

Comment: Jeeped I only want it to change one cell so I can autofill

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good time to use `Selection` rather than avoiding it.

```
Sub Find_Bad_Replace_Good()
    Dim rng As Range, v As Long, vList As Variant
    With Selection.Parent
        vList = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
        For Each rng In Selection
            For v = LBound(vList, 1) To UBound(vList, 1)
                If CBool(InStr(1, rng.Value2, vList(v, 1), vbTextCompare)) Then
                    rng = vList(v, 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next v
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

Make a selection of one or more cells and run the macro. The list of replacement words are expected to be in column A of the same worksheet starting in A1.